# Hive cannot read ORC if set "orc.create.index"="false" when loading table

Tags: hadoop, hive, orc

Hive version: 1.2.1, create a table by the below:

```
CREATE TABLE ORC_NONE(                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
    millisec bigint,

...

)

 stored as orc tblproperties ("orc.create.index"="false");
 insert into table ORC_NONE select * from ex_test_convert;
```

But when giving query, it always return **NULL**. For example:

```
Select * from ORC_NONE limit 10;  // return blank
Select min(millisec), max(millisec) from ORC_NONE; // return NULL, NULL
```

I check the size of ORC_NONE, 2G, so it is not empty table, and if creating table by setting "orc.create.index"="true", queries work.

I was meant to test Hive performance on ORC with/without row indexes, more exactly, to test the skipping power of row indexes. However, it seemed that Hive can not read data when row index unavailable.

Is this a bug? Or something wrong with my loading?